# Update a column's value if its empty or '0' otherwise update the other column in the same table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I want to update my column player_a_id if its empty otherwise update player_b_id instead.

here is my table:
    **room**

```
+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
| room_id | room_no | room_name   | player_a_id | player_b_id | turn_of |
+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
|       1 |       1 | blah        |           1 |           3 |       0 |
|       2 |       5 | second room |           1 |           3 |       0 |
|       3 |       3 | 3rd room    |           4 |           5 |       0 |
|       4 |       4 | 4th room    |           6 |           7 |       0 |
+---------+---------+-------------+-------------+-------------+---------+
```

basically my goal is simple when a player joins a room it updates player_a_id otherwise if player_a_id is already occupied then update player_b_id instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the term `empty` means `NULL`,

```
UPDATE  room
SET     player_a_id = IF(player_a_id IS NULL OR player_a_id = 0, yourVal, player_a_id),
        player_b_id = IF(player_a_id IS NOT NULL OR player_a_id <> 0, yourVal, player_b_id)
WHERE   room_no  = '' // <<== (sample only) set your condition here....
```

Comment: you're welcome. the answer is not tested, need feedback if it works so I can update it if it won't.

Comment: it works fine, though if the player_a_id and player_b_id are both null then both are updated with the value intended only for 1.